# htacess mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page on my site called `map-xml.php` which is an RSS feed of housing properties. To enable me to submit this to Google's Data Feeds it needs to have an `.xml` file extension.

So how would I go about writing a rewrite rule in htaccess which would make `map-xml.xml` work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule ^(.*)/map-xml.xml$ /$1/map-xml.php [L]

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried that but it gave me the following error: 

Multiple Choices
The document name you requested (/map-xml.xml) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.

Available documents:

    * /map-xml.php (common basename)

Comment: Sorry, I used too many slashes.

`RewriteRule ^(.*)map-xml.xml$ $1/map-xml.php [L] ` 
works at my test server